# How do i go about getting working location "remote or in-office" and hours in Microsoft graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the MS Graph API to get the working hours of a user. Using the following endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxSettings/workingHours

This is currently returning a single set of working hours for the user. Here is the response from the above API call:[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcPec.png)

In outlook I am able to set different working location and hours  for the user. See outlook snippet below:[Outlook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqayU.png)

How do i go out about getting day based working hours and location using MS Graph API?

Comment: Not supported by the Graph API. You can create a new feedback https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ebe2edae-97d1-ec11-a7b5-0022481f3c80 I will definitely vote for this feature.